# how to start from different Activity in android studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

i make app with two activities.
firs has:

- 2 ExitText(login and password);
- button(confirm, save data with SharedPreferences, intent to second activity).

second one:

- 2 TextView(get login and password with SharedPreferences);
- button(clear data on SharedPreferences, intent to firsActivity).

how to make next: while there are some data on SharedPreferences - app will be started from the 2nd screen.

for example, i made:

if (user!=null && pass!=null){ Intent enterIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(enterIntent);
    }

but, technically it first run the firstActivity and than go to the secondOne. if there are some method to start app with the another activity (not mainOne)?

Comment: It very easy just clear your share preferences

Comment: And put you code so we can understand what is happing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to check to see if there are values in SharedPreferences before entering one Activity.

What you can do is check the value before displaying the UI (before calling `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)`), and either continue along, or start the next Activity.

```
public class MyStartActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (preferences.contains("my_key")) {
            // start next Activity
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    }

}
```

Comment: An important aside, don't store user credentials in `SharedPreferences`!

Comment: Thanks!
your code need only one modification - use ELSE:     
     if (preferences.contains("my_key")) {
            // start next Activity
        } **else** {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);    
it works good, thanks again!

Comment: OP didn't specify the behaviour explicitly - this code will keep the initial activity in the back stack with its UI initialised. If this is not required, calling `finish(); return;` at the end if the `if` block is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the first one on the back stack, you can call finish() after starting the second one (or use appropriate flag(s) on intent).

Another approach would be to have only one activity with to fragments and decide dynamically which one set on start. With fragments you can also easily change layouts on button click or on back pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work, because app has to start at the first activity. First activity checks login and pass at share preferences and then you can go to the second activity

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (preference.getSting("key",null)!= null) {
            // start new Activity
            //finish this activity so it not in back stack
        } else {

        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Activity aliases would not provide a way to solve this problem.